# Im not getting any returned value from this... why?

Tags: php, mysql

Yes it connects to the database, everything else works fine. I cant seem to pull the pass from the db its showing no returned `echo`

```
 <?php

$username="test";
    include("db.php");

     $con=mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd) //connect to the database server
or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($db_name)  //select the database
    or die ("Could not select to mysql because ".mysql_error());

$query="select password from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
            $result=mysql_query($query,$con) or die('error');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
        $un_pass_s1=$row['password'];
    echo $un_pass_s1;
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You're doing a lot of other things wrong, from using deprecated `mysql_*` functions to (apparently) storing passwords in plain-text in the database. If you're following a tutorial, you should abandon it and find one which uses PDO.

Comment: @Kermit thank you :) I Im using old code but rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` loops until `$row` is false. The loop body is a single empty statement, `;`. You need to put your code which accesses `$row` *inside* the loop, not after it.

Comment: I have no idea what a loop body is? You give me an example of proper syntax?

Comment: Are you not going to give me an example?

Comment: I've no intention of doing so, no. My answer is very clear. If you want to learn the syntax for while loops, go look at the documentation or any PHP tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=mysql_query("select password from ".$table_name." where username='$username'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$un_pass_s1=$row['password'];
}
echo "value=".$un_pass_s1;
```